# Cannot drag entire Desktop to an extended monitor on Mojave

Tags: display, desktop, mission-control, mojave

I have several application windows open in one of the desktops on my MackBook Pro (late 2016) running Mojave 10.14, and my work requires me to use extended monitors. Whenever I wanted to move a maximized application window to the extended monitor from my MBP, all I have to do is just pull up the mission control and simply drag the maximized application window over to the extended display monitor. But when I try to drag a desktop that has some application windows open in it, say terminal and sublime windows resized to fit either half of the screen it does not allow me to drag that particular desktop to the other monitor. That leaves me having to open up and arrange the application windows separately on the  extended monitor. Is there a way to just simply drag the desktop from one monitor to the other? [image]

Comment: Can you edit to make a little more clear maybe pictures? If I understand correctly you want to move the entire arrangement of windows from one monitor to another.